# Não consigo "pegar" um elemento no Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Olá, boa noite! Estou tendo um problema para capturar o elemento da senha no WebDriver.

Eu coloco o caminho da label e mesmo assim não consigo capturar o campo da senha.

Alguém já teve esse problema? Também não consegui pegando o XPath.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode fazer um MWE?

Comment: Andreia se trata de um site público, você poderia compartilhar a url? As vezes a label pode estar dentro de um iframe e você precisa acessá-lo antes, tenta buscar por algum iframe.